folder.getFiles() shows length of zero even though the drive folder has multiple files
I'm trying to access the files within my Google Drive folder and create a sheet with the names of the files in the folder and the links to the files on the Drive folder.  I have the folder ID and using the following lines of code, but the folder returned is empty
function retrieveFiles() {

  var folderid = '1R07zv6TK9ka_BX--EMucP4pFlqYUsDJH';
  Logger.log(folderid);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid);
  Logger.log(folder.getName());
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  Logger.log(files);
  var data = [];

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileUrl = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + file.getId();
    data.push([file.gerName(), fileUrl]);
  }
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getrange(1,1,data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

}


The folderid is correct and I have access to said folder
screenshot of folder id in Chrome
When I run the code, the value returned for folder when I call the folder.getFiles() shows length of zero even though the drive folder has 11 files (3 spreadsheets and 8 documents)
Chrome debugger variables
I added Logger.log... the FileIterator does not show any data
Execution Log

I think we need more information to be able to help you with whatever you're doing. Can you share more of your code to explain what actions you're taking after these three lines? I don't understand what you mean by return null. If you added Logger.log(files) right now, it would reflect 'FileIterator', which is how you can iterate through large file collections.

Based on the copy and paste I'm seeing, there's two typos: gerName instead of getName when you're pushing data to the array and the last line should be sheet.getRange (uppercase R).

Please don't add text data by using images. Add this data as text.

From the question

When I run the code, the value returned for folder when I call the folder.getFiles() shows length of zero even though the drive folder has 11 files (3 spreadsheets and 8 documents)

DriveApp.Folder.getFiles() returns a DriveApp.FileIterator object, not an Array of elements, as you expect.
If you want to count the number of files in a folder, based on your code, use data.length.
Related

google-apps-script count files in folder
Count files in Google Drive folder


This is provided for your reference.
Proper logging is important.
function retrieveFiles() {
  const folderId = '1R07zv6TK9ka_BX--EMucP4pFlqYUsDJH';
  Logger.log('folderId: %s', folderId);
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  Logger.log('+ folderName: %s', folder.getName());
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  const data = [];

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const file = files.next();
    Logger.log('+-> fileName: %s', file);
    const fileUrl = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + file.getId();
    data.push([file.getName(), fileUrl]);
  }

  if (data.length > 0) {
    console.log('=== numFiles: %s', data.length);
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  }
}

